# Apple Mach-O Linker error when testing for device

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, ios5

I am getting this error Apple Mach-O Linker error, when I am testing on my iPad. 
Although it is working well on simulator. 
I have checked all the frameworks, but still the error stays.

Heres what the error says:

```
 ld: library not found for -lz 
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I dont understand whats going wrong. Please any ideas.. ?

Appreciate your time in advance
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without further info I'd say you have som library only compiled for the simulator not the device.

Comment: How can we install that library/compile for the device..  ?

Comment: I have no clue. Above is the only error log I am getting. Its driving me nuts since morning :( , Also cant find any help/info on google, regarding this " library not found for -lz "

Comment: are u using any custom libraries ie not dev. by apple?

Comment: Since I am working on game, I am using Kobol2D workspace which includes cocos2d, box2d, nothing other that this..!